# GTK application don't run in windows

Tags: c#, gtk, monodevelop

I develop a little test to study C# and GTK. In linux, this works perfectly, but when I try to run this in windows never works. The project is a simple calc.

In these windows I install:

- dotNetx45_Full
- gtk2runtime-2.24.10-2012-10-10
- gtk-sharp-2.12.45

At this moment when I run in windows the feedback in windows events is:

```
Application: Calculadora.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Information: System.DllNotFoundException
Stack:
   in GLib.Object.gtksharp_register_type (IntPtr, IntPtr)
   in GLib.Object.RegisterGType (System.Type)
   in GLib.Object.LookupGType (System.Type)
   in GLib.Object.LookupGType ()
   in GLib.Object.CreateNativeObject (IntPtr [], GLib.Value [], Int32)
   in Gtk.Window..ctor (Gtk.WindowType)
   in Calculator.MainClass.Main (System.String [])
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Hi Rafael, Welcome to StackOverfllow. `System.DllNotFoundException` is an exception which is telling you there is a missing dependency. I recommend you to put a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch` in the first line of `main` method and check the exception more detailed. It could tell you which dll is missing.

Answer (score 0):

That is odd. Gtk# says it targets gnome 2.20. It may be that you have some conflict between the versions in Gtk# and those in the Gtk2 runtime which look newer (2.24). I believe you should not need this runtime as the Gtk# installer should come with a runtime. It looks like the version of glib being loaded at runtime knows nothing about IntPtr. Could you have downloaded the mono version of gtk# rather than the .Net version? Try https://dl.xamarin.com/GTKforWindows/Windows/gtk-sharp-2.12.45.msi